# Run script if screen size is more than X

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, window

I have a code that I need to run if the screen size is more than 1024px, but it is not working... What is wrong with it?

```
if($(window).width() >= 1024){
    var targetOffset = $("#section--4").offset().top;

        var $w = $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ( $w.scrollTop() + 200 > targetOffset ) {   
                $("#logo").fadeIn(500);
                $("#logo2").fadeOut('slow');
                $("header").css({"overflow": "hidden"});
            } else {
                $("#logo2").fadeIn(2000)
                $("#logo").fadeOut('fast');
                $("header").css({"overflow": "visible"});
            }
   }
});
```

Comment: You may need to bind it to the `$(window).on('resize')` event

Comment: What do you mean? I'm starting with jQuery

Comment: what part of the code is not working? the entire part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(window).resize(function(){
 if($(window).width() >= 1024){
    var targetOffset = $("#section--4").offset().top;
    var $w = $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ( $w.scrollTop() + 200 > targetOffset ) {   
            $("#logo").fadeIn(500);
            $("#logo2").fadeOut('slow');
            $("header").css({"overflow": "hidden"});
        } else {
            $("#logo2").fadeIn(2000)
            $("#logo").fadeOut('fast');
            $("header").css({"overflow": "visible"});
        }
      });
   }
});
```

Without Resize

```
 if($(window).width() >= 1024){
    var targetOffset = $("#section--4").offset().top;
    var $w = $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ( $w.scrollTop() + 200 > targetOffset ) {   
            $("#logo").fadeIn(500);
            $("#logo2").fadeOut('slow');
            $("header").css({"overflow": "hidden"});
        } else {
            $("#logo2").fadeIn(2000)
            $("#logo").fadeOut('fast');
            $("header").css({"overflow": "visible"});
        }
      });
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that is breaking the website... I don't know why, because your code seems all right...

Comment: This is almost working! The thing is that it only works if I resize the window, but it the screen is already bigger than 1024px, it doesn't work. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: @patie Added Code for your requirement.

Comment: Thanks! Needed to add $(function () { on the top of it, so now works!

Answer (score 1):

You simply need this

```
$(window).on('resize', handler )
```

Here's a simple example. Click on the full page link at the bottom of the code and then resize the browser to see the box fade out when width of browser is less than 500.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$(window).on('resize', function(){

if($(window).width() >= 500){
    var targetOffset = $("#section--4").offset().top;

        $(window).scroll(function() {
        $("#logo").text($(this).scrollTop());
            if ( $(this).scrollTop() + 200 > targetOffset ) {   
                $("#logo").fadeIn(500);
                $("#logo2").fadeOut('slow');
                $("header").css({"overflow": "hidden"});
            } 
            else{
                $("#logo2").fadeIn(500);
                $("#logo").fadeOut('slow');
                $("header").css({"overflow": "visible"});
            }
   });
}

});

});
```

```css
#logo{
width:60px;
height:60px;
background:pink;
position:fixed;
}

#logo2{
width:60px;
height:60px;
background:yellow;
position:fixed;
}

#section--4{
width:60px;
height:60px;
background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
<div id="logo">logo</div><br />
<div id="logo2">logo2</div>
<div id="section--4">section--4</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<div></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I also need $(window).scroll(function(). So is there a way to create apply all my code to yours $(window).on('resize', function() ?

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is the following :

Use the `$(document).ready` to execute a piece of code once the page is loaded.

Wrap the code you already have in a function (let's say we named that function `func` for the example).

Do the following :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  func();
  $("window").on('resize', func);
});
```

This piece of code executes the function `func` when the page is loaded and attaches an event listener to the `window` object's resize event and will call `func` whenever the `resize` event is fired on the `window` object.